# Improve rolling mean usage in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to put together a function which will replicate the following

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(data.table)
library(parallel)
library(RcppRoll)

windows <- (1:10)*600

df2 <- setDT(df_1, key=c("Match","Name"))[
  ,by=.(Match, Name), paste0("Period_", 1:10)
  := mclapply((1:10)*600, function(x) roll_mean(Dist, x))][]
```

It creates a rolling average based off the values assigned to `windows`
I have a working function which replicates it however, I have a feeling there's a better way of doing it as the function version takes almost 30 times longer to process the data

```
dt_rolling <- function(df, the.keys, x, y, z, window){
  df <- data.table(df)
  setkeyv(df, the.keys) 
  df[,by=.(x,y), paste0("Period_", window) := mclapply(window, function(a) roll_mean(z, a))][]
}


df2 <- dt_rolling(df_1, the.keys=c('Match', 'Name'), df_1$Match, df_1$Name, df_1$Dist, windows)
```

The data in question looks like this

```
> dput(head(df_1, 5))
structure(list(Match = c("BathH", "BathH", "BathH", "BathH", 
"BathH"), Name = c("Alafoti Faosiliva", "Alafoti Faosiliva", 
"Alafoti Faosiliva", "Alafoti Faosiliva", "Alafoti Faosiliva"
), Dist = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Period_1 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), Period_2 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), Period_3 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), Period_4 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), Period_5 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), Period_6 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), Period_7 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), Period_8 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), Period_9 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), Period_10 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), Period_600 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), Period_1200 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), Period_1800 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), Period_2400 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), Period_3000 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), Period_3600 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), Period_4200 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), Period_4800 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), Period_5400 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), Period_6000 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), sorted = c("Match", "Name"), class =     c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), .internal.selfref = <pointer:   0x10280cae0>)
```

It can extend to over 20 million rows so that's why I'm using a `data.table` approach here along with investigating changing it to a function

Comment: The source of `roll_mean()` is not contained in your question, nor `run_sum_v2()`. It is difficult to understand what exactly you need. Can you please provide a complete minimal reproducible example? THX :-)

Comment: `roll_mean()` is from the `RcppRoll` package. I replaced `run_sum_v2()` with a similar function also from `RcppRoll` package. Within my script I have `Rcpp` based C++ functions to speed up the rolling sum/average

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38917435/fast-rolling-mean-summarize

Comment: I edited the title because the original one was quite meaningless

Comment: The issue wasn't speed of the analysis it's that I have to use it multiple times in my script and looking for a way to turn it into a custom function without the loss of of performance which occurs with my attempt at a custom function

Comment: @NColl thanks for benchmarking, please include microbenchmark call and code to produce data so others can re-run your benchmark.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fast rolling mean is available in data.table since v1.12.0 version.
Following query will address your question.

```
df_1[, paste0("Period_", windows) := frollmean(Dist, windows)]
```

---

adding some benchmark, unfortunately doesn't work for RcppRoll. Changed from mclapply to lapply for easier seeing the error.

```r
library(data.table)
library(parallel)
library(RcppRoll)

windows = (1:10)*600
N = 1.5e6

set.seed(108)
dt = data.table(Match=letters[sample(26, N, TRUE)], Name=letters[sample(26, N, TRUE)], Dist=rnorm(N), key=c("Match","Name"))
dt1 = copy(dt)
dt2 = copy(dt)

system.time(
  a1 <- dt1[, paste0("Period_", windows) := lapply(windows, function(w) roll_mean(Dist, w)), by=.(Match,Name)]
)
#Error in roll_mean_impl(x, as.integer(n), as.numeric(weights), as.integer(by), :
#negative length vectors are not allowed

system.time(
  a2 <- dt2[, paste0("Period_", windows) := frollmean(Dist, windows),by=.(Match,Name)]
)
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.554   0.040   0.209
```

Comment: `** libs
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fopenmp -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c assign.c -o assign.o
clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
make: *** [assign.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘data.table’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/data.table’
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fopenmp -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c assign.c -o assign.o
clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
make: *** [assign.o] Error 1`

Comment: The `roll` branch wouldn't install for me with the above error occurring

Comment: @NColl openmp on mac is known issue, you can resolve it by following [devel data.table installation wiki](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

Comment: Comparison of `data.table::frollmean` to a `Rcpp` based rolling mean function added to original question.

Comment: @NColl thanks for benchmarking, please include microbenchmark call and code to produce data so others can re-run your benchmark.

Comment: @NColl you benchmark does not address the question. Computing multiple windows will use multiple CPUs, so will be faster than rcpp.

Comment: @NColl added code for benchmark to my answer, feel free to improve